# How to rig eyelid to follow non-spherical eyeball

Tags: rigging

i would like to rig sonic eyelid just like in the games.

here is my eyelid.

[image: sonic]

Comment: This surface looks spherical, but the whole sphere as big as the head or bigger. So probably you can solve it if you use really big bones for it, bigger then the radius of the head.

Comment: You start with spherical eye and eyelid that is easy to rig and then you use a lattice deformer to make both into the shape you want.

Comment: giving the geometry, maybe the easiest way to do it is to use shape keys?

Comment: ive already tried shape keys, but i could never get it to slide down withouth clipping the eyeballs bad.

Comment: yes bad idea actually, so I guess bones are the solution

Comment: is there a way to make it scale in on a curve like a garage door?

Comment: it might work but bones seem to be an easy way to do it, please take a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Shapekeys and lattice would probably not give satisfying results, so you could use a system of bones and create a series of poses to open and close your eyes. Giving the curve of your eyes, 3 poses should be necessary and enough. You'll probably need to scale one or two bones so that it sticks to the eye and don't emerge out of the face. Also, you may need more bones if you want to be more precise (like 3 horizontal rows of 2 bones instead of 3x1).

The method: create 3 bones within your character armature and parent them to the head bone. Here there is one bone for each row of faces (I've simplified your mesh). Give them names like *eyelid1_L*, etc... Parent the mesh to the armature *With Empty Groups*, then assign each faces row to the vertex group it is supposed to be part of, i.e. the group with the name of the bone that is supposed to control it. Now when you'll move a bone, the corresponding part of the mesh will follow.

[image]

Comment: Lattis does not work as i want, it also needs to b part of my existing armature

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6390" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6390/)

Comment: i need the eyes to slide straight down like a beanie around a head

Comment: ok, edited, I've used some bones and I think it works fine

Answer (score 1):

A simple way in this particular context (unconventional to do that and with some limitations, though, but very easy) may be duplicating the eye. Shift it a bit so that it becomes eyelid (change its color, etc).

Then use a boolean:

[image]

The boolean is set to the eyelid, with here a cube to change the opening of the eye (but could be another shape, another orientation, etc.).
[image]

Comment: ok ill try these methods out

Comment: the booeon bethod wont work for me as i want to use my eyelid model, and the bone method i dont know how to do fully

Comment: ok, tried to give something very simple to do. But I think if you want to use your model, you'll need to use bones (and so learn to do it). Should accept moonboots answer.

Comment: i agree bones are the way to go